# Inserting html tables in JLabel in JFrame using Java

Tags: java, swing

I am a new learner of java and got an assignment which is pretty tough for me. In this assignment I have to create a table using JFrame and JLabel. In the JLabel I want to create this table using HTML's `"<table></table>"`. For this purpose I used a while loop to enter various `<tr>`s and `<td>`s with values and insert it in JLabel. However I don't know how I can do that.

Below is the code I have written:

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class Multiplikationstabell {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Tabell t1 = new Tabell();
        t1.elements();
    }

}

class Tabell extends JFrame {
    private JLabel label;

    public Tabell() {
        setTitle("Muliplikations tabell");

        this.label = new JLabel(elements());
        add(label);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
     public void elements() {
        System.out.println("<html><body><table border = '1'>");
        int rowNumber = 1;

        while (rowNumber <= 10) {
            int rowFields = 1;
            int multiplier = 1;
            int value = 1;
            value = value * rowNumber;
            System.out.println("<tr>");
            while (rowFields <= 10) {
                System.out.print("<td>" + value * multiplier + "</td>");
                multiplier++;
                rowFields++;
            }
            System.out.println("</tr>");
            rowNumber++;
        }
        System.out.println("</table></body></html>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We need to set the text of `JLabel` with the HTML content.

### Multiplikationstabell

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Multiplikationstabell {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Tabell t1 = new Tabell();
        String htmlConent = t1.elements();
        t1.label.setText(htmlConent);
    }
}
```

### Tabell

```
class Tabell extends JFrame {

   public JLabel label;

    public Tabell() {
        setTitle("Muliplikations tabell");
        this.label = new JLabel();
        add(label);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 400);
        // setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public String elements() {
        String htmlContent = "<html><body><table border = '1'>";
        int rowNumber = 1;
        while (rowNumber <= 10) {
            int rowFields = 1;
            int multiplier = 1;
            int value = 1;
            value = value * rowNumber;
            htmlContent += "<tr>";
            while (rowFields <= 10) {
                htmlContent += "<td>" + value * multiplier + "</td>";
                multiplier++;
                rowFields++;
            }
            htmlContent += "</tr>";
            rowNumber++;
        }
        htmlContent += "</table></body></html>";
        return htmlContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sagar.... that was a great help... instead of printing i should have made a string which didn't come to my mind... you are a perfect coder :)

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: 1) `String htmlContent` better to use `StringBuilder htmlContent` when repetitively adding to the string. 2) `setSize(400, 400);` Don't guess the size. Use `pack()` to have it calculated.

Comment: hi sagar routha... I am sorry for the late response... i am trying to accept the answer but it doesnt work.. its giving me an error...